# How I prep a concrete garage floor for painting?

Tags: concrete, painting

Is there any special considerations for painting a concrete garage floor as opposed to any other concrete surface?

I'm thinking in terms of foot and tire traffic.

[image: the floor]

Comment: **It is all about cleaning**, Grind or scrape or wire brush any old loose paint, Wash and scrub with TSP, ( Trisodium phosphate ), let dry vacuum well.  You must use a paint made for concrete. *If you provide a more detailed question with your plans we can elaborate and post an answer instead of comment*.

Comment: You can go even further and abrade the floor with a diamond grinder.  The more prep you do, the better the paint will stick and longer it will last.  It's a balance of time, money, and longevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an acid etch is about the best and easiest methods. Most masons use muriatic acid at 15-30% with water you can go stronger but this is normally strong enough to etch the surface looking at your photo 15% may be plenty. I use a 2 part epoxy made for garages , don’t go cheap or you may find where you park your vehicle the paint peeling where you stop when the tires are warm. With plain concrete paint I have seen it peel up along the tire path not just where the vehicle stops. Since you are in a garage there should be plenty of ventilation and ringing is easy with a squeegee (that’s what I use) a floor squeegee. I would caution a really nice coating looks super but I spilled some antifreeze on mine one day and it was so slick I could not stand up so now I add a traction powder, you really can’t see it but it is not so slippery.

Remember aaa always add acid to water to prevent an exothermic reaction and possibly having the acid splatter when it boils. 
muriatic is used in swimming pools to adjust ph all pool stores have it as do most home improvement stores for cleaning and etching concrete.

Comment: And by the way, never, never, never spray 2-part garage paint.  They never conceived of anyone spraying it, and so they don't tell you all the safety equipment you need.  Inhaling atomized paint *resin* is Very Bad, but it is harmless if it stays on the brush or roller. Yes, traction modifier is essential, and can be mixed with the paint or shaken on with a salt or parmesan shaker as you lay the first coat.  (So it's trapped between coats).

Comment: Absoutly never spray only roll, thanks Harper I never thought of that!